# Sqlite for windows store doesn't search for arabic text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I am using sqlite for my windows 8 store app. I've been querying a lot of things successfully, but recently i tried to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM QuranText where AyaWithoutTashkeel LIKE '%الم%'
```

This always returns 0 results and the same for any arabic text, however when the text is English:

```
SELECT * FROM Translation where TranslationText LIKE '%all%'
```

it's valid and it returns results.

of course I'm sure that the database itself has the same values and everything. My other app (a WP8 app) however returns results in both queries. using the same .sqlite database and using sqlite of course.

I'm thinking it's a kind of encoding problem maybe?

Comment: What are the actual character values in the database column and in the search string?

Comment: Maybe try converting the arabic characters to unicode-escaped characters? Like `'&#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0645;'`. You could try a couple from [here](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) to see which works.

Comment: Well, I tried them all and nothing seems to be working. something is really strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trials, we came to the solution to this. Apparently the SQLlite layer over the SQL database only recognize Arabic letters when it's entered in a parameterized query style like this:

```
//define your connection here
static SQLite.SQLiteConnection dbConn = = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(file.Path);
//in your method that makes the call:
string text="الم";
dbConn.Query<DB.QuranText>(@"SELECT * FROM QuranText where AyaWithoutTashkeel LIKE", "%" + text + "%");
```

This is the only way that worked.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

I tested your query and it worked locally for me. What is your encoding type?

You can query your encoding type with this command:

```
PRAGMA encoding;
```

It should be UTF-8. If it isn't, you can update the encoding with this command:

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
```

Comment: Now it crashes with unhanded exception in SQLite.cs says: near "'%???%'": syntax error, I think it's at least we know now it's encoding issue!

Comment: I tried to do this from a DB explorer outside of windows-store C# code, and it returns utf8, however I don't know how to excute this from C# code?

Comment: something to add, that this query works perfectly when used from windows phone project using sqlite, windows store app is the problem here.

Comment: can you possibly tell how did you get it to work and query arbic text with windows store app?