# How to search in Arabic Text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am storing arabic text in sqlite database in my wp8 app. Below is an example of the arabic text stored in the sqlite file.

ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ

The user would be able to search like below:

الحمد

this should return the above text, but I know in normal it doesn't.
I am using very simple query in sqlite

```
select * from tbl where ArabicText like '%الحمد%'
```

and in c#

```
query = "select * from tbl where ArabicText like '%"+textToSearch+"%'"
```

The result is zero records, How should I search to retrieve the above single record?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sqlite for windows store doesn't search for arabic text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992506/sqlite-for-windows-store-doesnt-search-for-arabic-text)

Comment: not duplicate it is about sqlite

Comment: This is the problem I faced, I know it's not duplicate question. The answer provided in the answer of that question is not the answer for my question and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Try to write parameter query like `query = "select * from tbl where ArabicText like ?";
cmd.CommandText = query;
textToSearch = "%" + textToSearch + "%";
OleDbParameter paramText = new OleDbParameter("ArabicText", textToSearch);
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramText);`

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer, is to just use base64_encode on queries going into the database, and decode on information coming out (both while saving and while searching). It's not elegant, but it allows UTF characters into a non-UTF database.

Comment: The sqlite db file can store UTF chars and I have already stored these chars (string) in sqlite file.

Comment: It query 6236 records without the parameter.

Comment: perform with these few changes and try output response. Does it display. `%ٱلْحَمْدُ%` `%ح%`

Comment: It works perfect with that, but I cannot pass such string to my search text.